# Alternative for the lamda (=>) syntax on properties in C# 4?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, static, singleton

For example i want to have following class (written in newer c# version):

```
public class Database
{
    static Lazy<Database> _instance = new Lazy<Database>(() => new Database());
    public static Database Instance => _instance.Value;
    private string connectionString = "";
    public SqlConnection Connection => new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

How can i do this in C# version 4?

Comment: Try with `public static Database Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }` and  `public SqlConnection Connection { get { return new SqlConnection(connectionString); } }`

Comment: David, I've retitled your question. I think that's what you wanted. Please roll back if this is not what you meant.

Comment: Thanks :) it's alright @Mafii

Comment: Oh my god i am so stupid, i just realized => is the short form for get property xD

Comment: @DavidWalser please read my updated answer! These are called expression bodied properties btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, seems like I misunderstood you!

The `=>` sign is to return values (In the context of properties, it's also called an expression bodied property). It's a shortcut for the get syntax:

```
public int Test => 1;
```

is equal to

```
public int Test { get { return 1; } }
```

---

Original question/answer:

You use anonymous methods:

```
new Lazy<Database>(delegate() { return new Database() });
```

is behaving equally to

```
new Lazy<Database>(() => new Database());
```

You can read up some more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods